# ckan change group to organization

Tags: ckan

I am working on upgrading a currently working ckan site to a 2.x version. I have the system stood up on a server, following the documentation [of upgrading ckan](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/upgrading/upgrade-package-ckan-1-to-2.html) and following the [source install documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html). Now, our previous install included a sizable number (~30) of groups. These used to provide what organizations do (somewhat) in the newer version of the software. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963965/whats-the-difference-between-organizations-groups-in-ckan) provides a good distinction between groups and organizations on ckan. **So, is there a way to port these groups into organizations, and have the organizations own the datasets?** I need a way to automate this, as there are many datasets (up to 600) for each group, and data providers need a way to keep these datasets updated. Thanks for any help you can give me/1

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to write a little script to do this.

You could do this in python using the client https://github.com/ckan/ckanapi and call group_list() then on each one do a group_show() followed by organization_create(). The dict for an organization wouldn't be much
different to a group - try it and see.